# worflow rule from test class

Tags: workflowrule

I have a workflow rule that takes a picklist value and copies it to a text field.

Now, I want to pick only first 4 characters of the picklist and copy it in text field when the test class run.

Can I do that?Is it possible?

Comment: Can you demonstrate what you're tried so far? It might help us figure out what you're trying to do.

Comment: @sfdcfox, the issue is, the text field lenght is 4 and the picklist value thatthe workflow is copying to text field is more than 4. So Is it possible to just copy first 4 characters of the picklist to text field. The lenght cannot be changed now as it has integration related issues with it

Comment: How about changing the workflow rule to use LEFT(TEXT(Field__c), 4)?

Comment: i cannot change that as well, can i Instead change test class to take first 4 characters while updating?

Comment: if you are trying to make workflow behave differently in test than in non-test, then this scenario is not possible